# nftables with openvpn and lxc

Tags: debian, openvpn, lxc, nftables

I have a simple setup involving OpenVPN server in a LXC container (debian stretch host, debian buster container), in which i'd like to set up a firewall based on nftables.

What confused me is the fact that nftables could not catch saddr of any of the traffic in 10.52.1.0/24 subnet, not even with specific IP or /32 mask.

I discovered that nftables sees my traffic as **encapsulated**, even though I think i've set it to listen on tap52 interface (which is is purely an openvpn interface 10.52.0.0/16)

Is there something i'm doing wrong?

My nftables.conf is very simple:

```bsh
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {

    chain input_tap52 {
        type filter hook input priority 0;
        ip saddr 10.52.1.0/24 drop # This doesn't work
        #drop # This works
        meta nftrace set 1
    }

    chain forward_tap52 {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }

    chain output_tap52 {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }

}
```

nft monitor trace gives me this output:

```
trace id beade08f inet filter input_tap52 rule nftrace set 1 (verdict continue)
trace id beade08f inet filter input_tap52 verdict continue 
trace id beade08f inet filter input_tap52 
trace id d46433ce inet filter input_tap52 packet: iif "eth0" ether saddr 00:16:3e:00:00:00 ether daddr 00:16:3e:c3:6d:fb ip saddr 46.134.**.** ip daddr 10.0.3.253 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 53 ip id 0 ip protocol udp ip length 42 udp sport 3423 udp dport openvpn udp length 22 @th,64,96 17369369003734387519951732736
```

Comment: Can you show the rules that direct traffic to the `input_tap52` chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I made few false assumptions:

1) I've read somewhere that appending interface name to "input_" will automatically filter traffic from that interface, which was false.

2) I did see encapsulated traffic, but there also were some valid "10.52.0.0/16" packets, brodcast ones to be specific.

So finally I remembered THIS:
https://serverfault.com/questions/736274/openvpn-client-to-client

enabling **client-to-client** makes pakets **invisible** to kernel. This was the issue in my case.